# How I can pin a thread in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How I can pin a thread from `ForumChannel`?

Show the picture:

[image: Example ss]

```
test = await thread.create_thread(name="test", content="t---")
for a in test:
   await a.pins()
```

`thread` is the ForumChannel

Answer (score 1):

You can pin a thread in a ForumChannel by using `.edit()` on the thread

```
 test = await thread.create_thread(name="test", content="t---")
    
 # await thread.create_thread() returns a tuple(Thread, Message)
    
 await test[0].edit(pinned=True)
```

---

**Read more about them here**:

`.create_thread()`: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=thread#discord.ForumChannel.create_thread

`.edit()`: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=thread#discord.Thread.edit